# MenuItem icon distortion on Mac OS X by JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I am creating system menu bar by JavaFX on Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5 (14F27). JDK version I am using is 1.8.0_131.

The logic of the code looks like following:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private BorderPane createContent() {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem openMenu = new MenuItem("Open");
        ImageView openIcon =
                new ImageView(new Image(getUrl("/img/menus/open.png"), 16, 16, false,
                                        false));
        openMenu.setGraphic(openIcon);

        file.getItems().addAll(openMenu);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(file);
        menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
        return borderPane;
    }

    private String getUrl(String resourcePath) {
        return getClass().getResource(resourcePath).toExternalForm();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

But in real my application is very large and it has many menus.

[image]

From time to time menu icon is not being shown properly, and I don't know why.

[image]

I wonder if there any bug on JavaFX or Mac OS X. Maybe someone had faced with such a problem. Please share your solution if you had.

Comment: I don't find any problem in your code. May be the distortion is occurring for some other reasons. If this is the whole code then there shouldn't be any problem, i guess. Try specifying the scenario more

Comment: "*From time to time*" The behavior changes with every new launch of the application or with every opening of the menu? What if you don't `setUseSystemMenuBar(true)`?

Comment: It happens when I dynamically add something to the content and some new menus

Comment: You have to be more specific. Answer these questions: (1) Add what to the content of what? (2) Distortion occurs for first launch of what? Can you reset it? (3) When you switch to a different application and the menu is open do you see the distortion happen on switching? (4) What if you don't use `setUseSystemMenuBar(true)`? (5) What if you use a different image?

Comment: @user1803551 I need to use `setUseSystemMenuBar(true)`, because I want system menubar.

Comment: I will to try to write more detailed code, to show an issue

Comment: I have this same problem. It is intermittent across 3 different icons. If it happens, then it never goes away during the uptime of the application. If I reboot, then I roll the dice again as to whether it's going to happen.